# Redirecting TCP traffic to another destination

Tags: java, traffic, socketserver

I have a game client. Which connects to this game.
I'm trying to set up a socket server which intercepts all traffic to the game server(The game runs through the use of sockets)

My problem is that i would need to redirect all traffic my computer makes to the game servers ip + port to 127.0.0.1 to make it connect to the socket server i've made myself first.

I know i could use the windows hosts file but this redirects ALL traffic. I only want 1 port redirected(The one with TCP traffic) If the HTTP traffic also gets redirected it ruins everything.

I'm using windows 7

Comment: You might have more luck on serverfault. Also, you should update the question with the OS you're using.

Comment: Have you snooped your router settings (if this is just a personal project)? My belkin router can redirect traffic from specific ports or specific services to private, virtual servers.

Comment: It's a commercial product which will have several users. So it's bound to be "setup free"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Privoxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privoxy) can help you. It's a successor of Internet Junkbuster, as mentioned in the answer for the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332651/forwarding-only-on-a-single-port-8080-to-localhost-windows-possible).